# Edittext not stretching down to the available free space

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having a layout file activity_add_record . In that file there is a Edittext with id @+id/edtextview_note. It is not stretching down to the available free space. I used all the possibilities that I know.Please help me.Thanks in advance

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="#FEFCFF">  
   <ScrollView 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dip"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb"
       android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_track"
       android:scrollbarSize="3dip"
       android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">       
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtview_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="#181818"/>
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/autoview_friend_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dip"                   
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#181818"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:background="@drawable/activity_background"/>
            <requestFocus/> 
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtview_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Number"
                android:textColor="#181818"/>
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerview_numbers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dip"                      
                android:background="@drawable/activity_background"/>       
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtview_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email-id"
                android:textColor="#181818"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtxtview_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dip"                  
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#181818"
                android:background="@drawable/activity_background"/>       
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtview_category"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category"
                android:textColor="#181818"/>
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerview_category"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dip"                       
                android:background="@drawable/activity_background"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtview_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Birth Date"
                android:textColor="#181818"/>
            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/second_relative_layout" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtxtview_date"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgbtn_set_date"                                  
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:singleLine="true"                   
                    android:textColor="#181818"
                    android:background="@drawable/activity_background"/>       
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/imgbtn_set_date"
                    android:layout_width="75.0dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
                    android:text="SET"
                    android:textColor="#F8F8FF"
                    android:textSize="15sp" 
                    android:textStyle="normal"          
                    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                    android:contentDescription="SEARCH" 
                     android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>              
            </RelativeLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtview_notes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Notes"
                android:textColor="#181818"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtextview_note"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"       
                    android:hint="Notes:\nThings planned for the Birthday / Aniversary"       
                    android:singleLine="false" 
                    android:textColor="#181818"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
                    android:overScrollMode="always"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:background="@drawable/activity_background"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"/>
        </LinearLayout>      
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/custom_splitactionbar" 
        android:background="#FF6600" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="50.0dip" 
        android:padding="2dip">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_ok"          
            android:layout_width="155.0dip" 
            android:layout_height="40.0dip" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip" 
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
            android:contentDescription="ADD NEW RECORDS"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"/>
       <Button android:id="@+id/btn_revert"             
            android:layout_width="155.0dip" 
            android:layout_height="40.0dip" 
            android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip" 
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
            android:contentDescription="REVERT"
            android:text="Revert"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent view of your EditText, a LinearLayout, has its height set to `wrap_content` and hence it is doing as instructed in trying to wrap its height to all the childrens' heights. Hence, your EditText will have it's smallest suggested height, which is what you are observing.

I'm not entirely sure what you want, as the LinearLayout is enclosed inside a ScrollView, but perhaps you want to [use ScrollView's handy trick](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/) of having its immediate child fill the remaining height:

```
<ScrollView ...
        android:fillViewport="true" >
    <LinearLayout ...
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but it caused another problem the margin on the right

Comment: That is likely due to `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"`; it is increasing the margin to display the scrollbar outside of the view boundaries.

Comment: Thanks it works, but it caused another problem the margin on the right     side of the parent Linear Layout(child view of Scroll View) does not works that is stretched and layout looks not good . [link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/?savedsettings=11030311016#photo11030311016)